# Scroll view shifting down on enabling navigation bar in Android

Tags: android, listview, layout, scrollview, navigationbar

I am using fragments to display an image using `ImageView`, and `ScrollView` *below the image view* having some text using `TextView` in a `RelativeLayout`. Now the problem is that as seen in the image **[here](http://imgur.com/jZwUO7I)** there's a space created between the image and the scroll view when ever the navigation bar is enabled.

By enabling *show layout bounds* in the developer options, it's the image view creating the white space as seen **[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd2wt.jpg)**. There's no such space when viewed in the graphical layout on Eclipse.

Here's my `xml` of the fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:src="@drawable/city_image" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/fragment_main" />

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am new to Android and I apologize if I am making a silly mistake. I have tried to change scroll view's `gravity` to top and also played with `layout_height`. But still can't figure out what is wrong in my xml.